# Recover files deleted accidentally which are showing as 0 bytes

Tags: avi, file-recovery

I accidentally deleted a folder permanently. Nothing was written in that drive after it happened, so no danger of data rewritten on top of what was deleted (I have 2 hard drives, the one in which the files were is only for storage).

There were 2 **.avi files** in there that I'm trying to recover. They were recordings which used a **lossless codec (Lagarith)**. I tried several recovery software, but they all show those files as having **0 bytes**. I don't know what else I can do to recover these files. Hopefully someone can help me

Extra info:

- OS: Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits
- Hard Drive formatted with NTFS
- Files deleted are over 100 GBs
- In one of the software I tried, no header was showing for those files.
- I checked the drive using the windows tool under properties, and no problems  were found in it.
- I installed the recovery software in the my main hard drive of course, as to not rewrite on top of the deleted files.
- Other files I deleted which have the same format and used the same codec are not showing as 0 bytes. The difference is that they are significantly smaller and they were deleted directly (Not with a folder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I was having was most likely due to the fact that the file was huge. Not all recovery software can handle it. **R-Studio**, however, successfully restored both files.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your success and the product that helped you out! Did you use their R-Undelete product (http://www.r-undelete.com) or the Data Recovery product (http://www.r-studio.com)? The free version probably did not help you, or did it? If not, did you end-up buying the product?

Answer (score 0):

## STOP ALL YOUR WORK ON THIS PC! DON'T EVEN BROWSE! DISCONNECT THE PC FROM THE INTERNET!

Use another PC to browse and to find the undelete software (e.g. http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm).

Use a portable version. If you installed undelete s/w before you deleted the files it's no problem, but now you can't even install the undelete s/w or you might overwrite the deleted files.

Put a portable version on a USB (DO THIS ON ANOTHER PC) and then run it from on the affected PC from the USB Stick.

Once a portion of a "scattered" file has been overwritten, there is no way back!

Comment: I said twice in my post that nothing is being written to that drive.

Comment: When I read your post quickly, I wanted to make sure you did not overwrite any files. The fact that you see 0 bytes worries me. It would indicate that the FAT table is pointing immediately to a first sector that is already reused. I've heard from various people that the German PC Inspector recovery works wonders. Not sure about your situation though.  http://www.pcinspector.de/